# How to specify gradient in Pyomo with IPOPT

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo, ipopt

**Primary Question**

When solving a NLP in Pyomo, using IPOPT as the solver, how can I tell IPOPT what the gradient of the objective function and/or constraints are? I have to pass a callable function that returns objective values--can I likewise pass a callable function that evaluates the gradient as well?

**Secondary Question**

How does Pyomo+IPOPT handle this by default? When I solve a simple NLP with Pyomo+IPOPT, part of the IPOPT output includes "number of objective gradient evaluations"...but how is it evaluating the gradient? Numerically with finite differences, or something?

I'm using Pyomo 5.6 with Python 3.6 and IPOPT 3.7.

Comment: The relevance of this question for me comes from having a model trained outside of Pyomo/IPOPT (e.g., tensorflow), where the function is differentiable but doesn't have a closed-form expression.  It would be nice to be able to easily plug in the gradient information to IPOPT and not depend on the autodiff, in this case.  You can do this in  scipy but I don't know how the solvers there compare with IPOPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyomo provides first and second derivative information using the automatic differentiation features in the Ampl Solver Library (ASL). When calling IPOPT, Pyomo outputs your model using the '.nl' file format which is read by the ASL and linked to IPOPT. So you don't have to do anything to provide gradient information, this is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Could a user (in principle) provide a callable gradient, or does that feature not even exist? I read some about AD and it sounds like it’s pretty fast by itself

Comment: This is kind of supported. The ASL (and Pyomo) supports the idea of an External Function which require you to provide your own functions for evaluating first and second derivatives but these functions must be written in a language like C++ and compiled before they can be linked to a Pyomo model and evaluated in the ASL.

Comment: Ahh okay I see. Thanks for thorough answer and thanks for helping build Pyomo—it’s been a very useful tool!

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm behind is called [Autodiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation). Basically, it calculates the gradient of any function by using a representation as a graph of atomic functions (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and maybe exp and log). Then it uses the chain rule from calculus to calculate the whole gradient with respect to any input.